# Material Dialogs manage multiple dialogs z-index

Tags: angular-material, angular7, z-index, material-dialog

I have an application with multiple Angular Material dialogues opened at the same time with a drag and drop feature. What I want is when I click a modal it should be placed in front, is there a way to do that using Angular Material or at least a CSS trick.

Thank you

Comment: Please create stackblitz of your issue.

Comment: You can try to create a service where you save you last z-index and if you open another dialog you add 1 to it and apply this z-index to your dialog.